# Saber si un INSERT tuvo éxito o no

Tags: vba

Buenas tardes necesito una rutina que me  indique si la insercion desde vba tubo exito en una tabla el comando que uso para la insercion es este:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO historial (nombre, nro_identificacion) VALUES ('" & nom & "', '" & nro & "')"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

no he realizado nada porque no consigo instrucciones en internet que me ayuden a realizarlo. Agradezco ayuda

Comment: Cuenta el total de registros de esa tabla antes del insert. Guarda el resultado en una variable. Haz el insert. Vuelve a contar el número de registros de esa tabla. Si es diferente al anterior, es que tuvo éxito

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una variable `boolean`  en el `TryCatch`.Te adjunto el siguiente codigo que usa como ejemplo una conexion a MySQL:

```
    Dim iReturn as boolean
Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
        With sqlCommand
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO members_car (`car_id`, `member_id`, `model`, `color`, `chassis_id`, `plate_number`, `code`) values (@xid,@m_id,@imodel,@icolor,@ch_id,@pt_num,@icode)"
            .Connection = SQLConnection
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text // You missed this line
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@xid", "valor1")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@m_id", "valor2")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@imodel", "valor3")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@icolor", "valor4")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ch_id", "valor5")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@pt_num", "valor6")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@icode", "valor7")

        End With
        Try
            SQLConnection.Open()
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            iReturn = TRUE
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox ex.Message.ToString
            iReturn = False
        Finally
            SQLConnection.Close()
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

Return iReturn